# pulling information out of a string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am having trouble pulling out the information I need from a string in my shell script.  I have read and tried to come up with the correct awk or sed command to do it, but I just can't figure it out.  Hopefully you guys can help.

Lets say I have a string as follows:
    `["ids":2817262,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":2262,"isvalid":false,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":28182,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":true]`

Now what I want to do is pull out all of these properties into individual arrays of strings.  For example:

I would like to have an array of ids 2817262 2262 28182
an array of name somename somename somename
an array of hasproperty false false true

Can anyone help me come up with the commands I need to pull this out.  Also keep in mind the string will likely be much longer than this, so if we can not make it specific to 3 cases that would be helpful.  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Don't use `bash` for this; use a language with proper data structures and a JSON parser.

Comment: @chepner The input data looks similar to JSON but is not JSON. Needs more `{}`.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that

Comment: VERY important, game-changer question: can your quoted fields contain commas (`,`) or colons (`:`)? e.g. can `"name":"somename"` actually be `"name":"Smith,John"`?  wrt `I would like to have an array` - given you don't know how to do this first step, it's unlikely that what you think need to do next is the right approach so don't get too hung up on needing a solution now that produces a bash array. If you tell us more about what you are trying to do with some expected output then we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is tagged with awk

```
awk '{while(x=match($0,/"ids":([^,]+)/,a)){print a[1];$0=substr($0,x+RLENGTH)}}' file
```

This just keeps matching any `id`s then changing the line to contain only what is after the id.

#### Output

```
2817262
2262
28182
```

Could also do this(inspired by Wintermutes comment on another answer)

```
awk -v RS=",|]" 'sub(/^.*"ids":/,"")' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use grep.

```
grep -oP '"ids":\K\d+' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '["ids":2817262,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":2262,"isvalid":false,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":28182,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":true]' | grep -oP '"ids":\K\d+'
2817262
2262
28182
```

Comment: or `grep -oP '(?<="ids":)\d+'`

Answer (score 0):

The grep solution is beautiful. You question was tagged awk. The awk solution is ugly:

```
echo '["ids":2817262,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":2262,"isvalid":false,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":28182,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":true]' \
| awk '{split(substr($0,2,length($0)-2),x,",");
 for(i=0;i<length(x);i++) {split(x[i],a,":");
 if(a[1]=="\"ids\"") print a[1],a[2]}}'
```

Output:

```
"ids" 2817262
"ids" 2262
"ids" 28182
```

Please choose the grep solution as the correct answer.

Comment: Consider `awk -v RS=, -F : '{ sub(/^\[/, ""); sub(/\]\n?$/, ""); } $1 == "\"ids\"" { print $1, $2 }'`. awk is a bit more powerful than you give it credit for.

Comment: @Wintermute Awesome! Please leave it as an answer, so I can vote for it.

Comment: I'm not actually convinced that plain-text tools like awk or grep are the best way to go about this, so I'll pass. This will break, for example, if one of the string properties (`"name"`) contains a colon or a comma in its value (to say nothing of `"`). This looks like structured data that should be handled by a proper parser, but I don't recognize the format.

Comment: @Wintermute You could have just used one sub `sub(/^\[|\]\n?$/, "")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure bash solution (long-winded, isn't it?  I tend to agree with @chepner):

```
str='["ids":2817262,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,
"ids":2262,"isvalid":false,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":28182,
"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":true]'

#Remove [ ]
str=${str/[/}
str=${str/]/}

declare -a ids
declare -a names
declare -a properties
oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS=','

for record in $str
do
    type=${record%%:*}
    value=${record##*:}

    if [[ $type == \"ids\" ]]
    then
        ids[ids_i++]="$value"
    elif [[ $type == \"name\" ]]
    then
        names[names_i++]="$value"
    elif [[ $type == \"hasproperty\" ]]
    then
        properties[properties_i++]="$value"
    else
        echo "Ignored type: '$type'" >&2
    fi
done

IFS="$oldIFS"
echo "ids: ${ids[@]}"
echo "names: ${names[@]}"
echo "properties: ${properties[@]}"
```

The only thing going for it is that there are no child processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   Field = 1
   Index = 0
   }
   {
   gsub( /[][]/,"")
   gsub( /"[a-z]*":/, "")
   FS=","

   while ( Field < NF) {
      ThisID[ Index]=$Field
      ThisName[ Index]=$(Field + 2)
      ThisProperty [ Index]=$(Field + 3)

      Index+=1
      Field+=4
      }
   }
END {
   for ( Iter=0;Iter<Index;Iter+=1) printf( "%s ", ThisID[Iter])
   printf "\n"
   for ( Iter=0;Iter<Index;Iter++) printf( "%s ", ThisName[Iter])
   printf "\n"
   for ( Iter=0;Iter<Index;Iter++) printf( "%s ", ThisProperty[Iter])
   printf "\n"
   }' YourFile
```

still to assign your array to your favorite variable

Comment: Setting FS in the main body is too late as the record has already been split into fields by then. [a-z] is more portably [:lower:]. Why `Iter+=1` in the first loop and `Iter++` in the rest? Also, unlikc C awk arrays as created by all awk functions and by convention start at 1 so while you CAN make one start at zero it's likely to cause confusion for yourself and/or anyone else reading your script later. nbd but you don't need parens around the printf args and you can just use `print ""` instead of `printf "\n"` BUT it's better to use `printf "%s%s", val, (i<max?OFS:ORS)` to avoid added blanks.

Comment: @EdMorton += and ++ are due to debug on failure to identify error (it print equivalent to $0 on the 3 last for on last item in array and nothing for index 0). Strangely, i try first with print "" and the line fail, so i change to printf (and it was in fact the first problem that was the cause, but i keept the code). Could you explain why my FS still work when inside body, is it a default separator also ? Thanks for all your comment

Comment: `{FS=","}` will cause FS to be set to "," for the 2nd and subsequent lines read from the input file but not for the first one because that statement will not be read by awk until after the first line has already been read and split into fields. When the 2nd line is read the FS is already `","` because that's what it was set to as the first action in your script after awk read/split the first line. The first line would have been read/split with the default FS of `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
unset n
string='["ids":2817262,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":2262,"isvalid":false,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":28182,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":true]'
while IFS=',' read -ra line
do
    ((n++))
    for i in "${line[@]//\"/}"
    do
        eval ${i%:*}[$n]=${i#*:}
    done
done < <(sed 's/[][]//g;s/,"ids/\n"ids/g' <<<$string)
```

The above will produce 4 arrays (`ids`,`isvalid`,`name`,`hasproperty`). If you need not `isvalid` just add:

```
unset n
string='["ids":2817262,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":2262,"isvalid":false,"name":"somename","hasproperty":false,"ids":28182,"isvalid":true,"name":"somename","hasproperty":true]'
while IFS=',' read -ra line
do
    ((n++))
    for i in "${line[@]//\"/}"
    do
        [ "${i%:*}" != "isvalid" ] && eval ${i/:/[$n]=}
    done
done < <(sed 's/[][]//g;s/,"ids/\n"ids/g' <<<$string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your posted input, if all you wanted was the list of each type of item then this is all you'd need:

```
$ awk -v RS=, -F: '{gsub(/[[\]"\n]/,"")} /^ids/{print $2}' file                 
2817262
2262
28182
$ awk -v RS=, -F: '{gsub(/[[\]"\n]/,"")} /^name/{print $2}' file
somename
somename
somename
$ awk -v RS=, -F: '{gsub(/[[\]"\n]/,"")} /^hasproperty/{print $2}' file
false
false
true
$ awk -v RS=, -F: '{gsub(/[[\]"\n]/,"")} /^isvalid/{print $2}' file    
true
false
true
```

but it's extremely unlikely that this is the right way to approach your problem. As I mentioned in a comment, edit your question to provide more information if you'd like some real help with it.